# Is there a word for temporary-but-may-become-permanent?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Is there a word in English for a solution that is temporary, but may become permanent if no better solution is found? I thought of "provisional" but if there is something better than that I would like to know.

The context is a position which I will take upon myself if I can, but I am asking for a "temporary" volunteer to replace me now and to stay the replacement if my situation means that I cannot take the position.

Thanks.

Comment: I think your original idea of *provisional* is your best choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The postpositive adjective *pro tem* is sometimes used in this situation.

> **pro tem** |ˈˈproʊ ˈtɛm|
>   adverb & adjective
>
> for the time being : [as adv. ] *a printer that Marisa could use pro tem* | [as adj. ] a pro tem committee | [as postpositive adj. ] *the president pro tem of the Senate*.
>
> ORIGIN abbreviation of Latin **pro tempore**.

<sup>*[NOAD](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pro+tem?region=us&q=pro%20tem)*</sup>

As Robusto noted, this word does not necessarily imply that something or someone may become permanent, although my *Shorter Oxford* gives *next* as one definition of *pro tem*.

Answer (score 7):

Further possibilities to consider are *interim, transitional*, and *stopgap*.

Comment: Thank you, these words give me some fodder for the thesaurus.

Answer (score 4):

**probationary**

from

> **[probation](http://books.google.com/books?id=Vm_mNJiflwgC&pg=PA342&lpg=PA342&dq=%22actual+or+potential+detention%22&source=bl&ots=d0TXnKa4IR&sig=uftlZSk1s3NGM6u9cAARncrcj9k&hl=en&sa=X&ei=wVGdT8fGFcHjiAKph8hR&ved=0CCMQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22actual%20or%20potential%20detention%22&f=false)** 2. the process or period of testing or observing the character or abilities of a person in a certain role, for example, a new employee : for an initial period of probation, your manager will closely monitor your progress. ‒ *Oxford Dictionary of Difficult Words*

Comment: Thank you. I agree that probation does meet the definition that need, however I intend to project a positive face to the position. I wonder if there is a positively-connotated counterpart to 'probation'.

Answer (score 3):

A word sometimes used in these situations for this kind of position is "trial." That is, it is being considered for "permanence," but "the jury is still out" (pun intended).

Comment: The word trial sounds as if the outcome depends upon the temporary member's performance, whereas the outcome of this situation depends on my own circumstances.

Comment: @dotancohen: They're evaluating you, you're evaluating them, but it seems like at least one is "trying out" the other.

Answer (score 2):

You may look at a word like *interim*:

> The use of a sump pump was an interim solution, but it could become permanent if nothing better shows up.

The thing is, any word that implies something being used as a stopgap (i.e., temporary) measure, will not automatically imply that it may become permanent. That information would have to be added. Still, any temporary solution may become a permanent one; that is understood.